# Error estimation for taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

It is claimed that

> $$ \ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}$$ for all $x \in (-1,1]$.

My reference then continues by estimating the error for partial sums of this series:

$$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\right] + E_{n}(x)$$

Using Taylor's Theorem with remainder in Lagrange's form gives

$$E_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{n} \left\lvert\frac{x}{1+\xi_{n}} \right\rvert ^n$$,

where $\xi_{n}$ is some real number between $x$ and $0$.

Certainly $| E_{n} | \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ if $|\frac{x}{1+\xi_{n}} | ^n <1.$

We also have $|  x | \leq 1$ and $| \xi_{n} |<1$  as the R.O.C. is $R=1$ by the ratio test.

My reference now claims, **and this is what I don't understand**, that this is true just when $x \in [-\frac{1}{2},1]$.

But surely if, say, $x=-3/4 \notin [-\frac{1}{2},1]$ it could be that and $\xi_{n}=-1/2$ and the inequality is still satisfied. So what am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=-3/4$ and $\xi=-1/2$, then $$\left\lvert \frac{x}{1+\xi}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{3/4}{1-1/2}\right\rvert=\frac32$$ so you cannot say $E_n\to 0$.

In fact this doesn't happen, but you need to do more work to show it.

Comment: Oh that's silly of me... But where does the $[-0.5,1]$ come from then?

Comment: The $-\frac12$ comes from setting $x=\xi$, which is the "worst case" scenario $\lvert x/(1+\xi)\rvert=1$ (remember $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$).  If $x>0$ then $\xi>0$ so $\lvert x/(1+\xi)\rvert<\lvert x\rvert$ so $E_n<x^n/n\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I see it now!